# Uploading A File To A Folder In An Azure Blob Container Using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm needing to upload files to a folder within a blob container (`BlobContainer\Files\` where `BlobContainer` is the container name and `Files` is the folder within the container), but when I pass that into the `-Container` parameter, it fails because it can't find that blob container.  Is there a way to specify a *specific folder* within a blob container when uploading a file using the `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` or if not, an alternate route to do this?

The below is the snippet of what I'm calling after logging in:

```
$storageacct = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString "CONNECTIONSTRING"
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File "E:\Files\file.txt" -Container "BlobContainer" -Context $storageacct
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure Storage, you don't have folders. Inside a container, you upload blobs. You can add a "prefix" to the blob name giving this idea of folders as the following:

```
$containerName = "blobcontainer"
New-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $ctx -Permission blob

# upload a file
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File "D:\_TestImages\Image001.jpg" `
  -Container $containerName `
  -Blob "Foldername/Image003.jpg" `
  -Context $ctx
```